# Can skeletal champions or other intelligent skeletons talk?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead

Can skeletal champions or other intelligent skeletons talk? I notice skeletal spell casters get silent spell as a bonus feat, but they also retain language and intelligence.

Comment: Is a lich considered a skeleton for purposes of this question?

Comment: No. I just mean skeletons. Lich's are a much more complex creature and i specifically want to know about skeletons and skeletal champions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Probably.

There are two pieces of indirect evidence I'd like to point to.

Firstly, while [skeletal mages](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/skeletal-mage/) (as you rightly point out) gain Silent Spell as a bonus feat, none of their prepared spells are actually modified by it. Wizards can't spontaneously apply metamagic to their spells like sorcerers can, so as written skeletal mages can't actually cast any of their spells unless they're able to speak. It seems unlikely that GMs are expected to reprepare a skeletal mage's spells every time one is encountered.

Secondly, take a look at the [Gashadokuro](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/gashadokuro/), a strange creature that's basically a skeleton made up of lots of smaller skeletons. Specifically, look at this line:

> **Languages:** Common (can't speak)

This is an "exception that proves the rule" (an often-misused phrase!), meaning the fact that this creature specifically *cannot* speak indicates that most creatures with a Languages entry can.